# Frequency Plot in R

Tags: r, histogram, frequency

I have an array of numbers (called tails.Z) ranging from 0 to 999 and I want to see which numbers appear most frequently. In order to do so, I do a simple frequency plot using `hist(tails.Z, breaks=1000)` with the following result:
[image]

According to the plot, the most frequent number appears over 400 times and is some value close to zero. A second peak is somewhere around the value of 200 and indicates that the number appears just short of 400 times.

However, when I do `sort(table(tails.Z))` to see the actual numbers and their frequencies I get that the most frequent number is 175 which appears 377 times, then the 2nd most frequent number is 176 which appears 290 times, then 3 which appears 266 times, 0 255 times and 5 263 times. How is it possible that the first peak in the graph is higher than 400 but in `table` there is no number with that frequency?

EDIT: I should add that tails.Z is an array of integers ranging from 0 to 999 and that there is 114,411 elements in it.

Comment: You didn't say how many elements are in `tails.Z`, but you're breaking it into 1000 discrete groups. While no single element may appear that frequently, a combination of elements that have been binned together will have a higher spike.

Comment: Try `hist(tails.Z, breaks=seq(0,1000), include.lowest=T)` or `barplot(table(tails.Z))`. Histograms aren't meant for discrete data really. Or maybe `with(as.data.frame(table(tails.Z)), plot(as.numeric(tz), Freq, type="h"))`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks: `with()` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

See what `hist` function does using `str`:

```
hs=hist(tails.Z, breaks=1000)
str(hs)
tail(cbind(hs$mids,hs$counts),20)
barplot(hs$counts)
summary(hs$counts)
```